# How to create an add-in/plugin for Outlook 2013 software

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, visual-studio-2015, add-in

I want to create an add-in/plugin for Outlook 2013. Here's what I am trying to achieve.
1) Every day when the Outlook user opens his Outlook application, he gets a small pop-up asking "Are you taking the cab service today?". He has three buttons which he can click Yes, No and Maybe. 
2) The add-on should collect this input and the email ID of the user and send it to a webpage where I can display this information.

How do I go about it? Where do I start? Which application do I use to write the code for this add-in/plugin?

I have Visual Studio 2015 community installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first stop should be the MSDN Office developer site. That will allow you to review all options available in the SDK.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905340.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started with an Outlook add-in quickly.

You may consider handling the [Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx) event of the Application class where you can display a dialog with options.